# Sending ipv6 packet

Tags: linux

I want to send an ipv6 packet from one machine to another from terminal. Can anyone tell me any command for this? I tried  `echoping -6 fd06:63df:059d:a45c::1` command but i got an error  `The syntax hostname:port is only for HTTP or ICP`

Answer (score 3):

Try ping6.

Alternatively, try the following:

```
echoping -6 '[fd06:63df:059d:a45c::1]'
```

IPv6 addresses can be enclosed by square brackets if confusion with the port syntax (i.e. append colon and port number) is possible. In this case I've also escaped the square brackets as they tend to get interpreted by the shell.

**Edit:**
This still doesn't work for echoping, but that's because of a bug in the program. The man page claims it supports RFC2732 style IPv6 addresses, but it does not. It explicitly checks for ':' in the address and refuses to accept it.

A workaround could be to insert a dummy name into /etc/hosts and then use that name as the target. Ideally you'd just fix echoping of course ;)

Comment: `ping6` sends ICMP packets. I want to send TCP or UDP packets which is possible with `echoping`. But your command gives me the same error as before.